# What is environment path when call method in referenced project?

Tags: c#, docker, api, asp.net-core

There two project in a solution which one of them is referenced another.
Project 1: .NET Core MVC
Project 2: .NET Core API

Both projects are docker enabled with Linux as OS.

Project 2 has Project 1 as **referenced** project.

A method for saving file on server is in Project 1, it is used for saving file in wwwroot/folder.

An API is in Project 2 for to be consumed outside.

When I call the API, referenced method will be called but the path for saving file raised an exception like as below:

> Could not find a part of the path '/app/D:\dev\Project1\wwwroot\folder

Saving file method:

```
    StringBuilder xmlFilePath = new StringBuilder();

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings))
    {
        doc.Save(writer);
        var xmlString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

        var pathFolder = _configuration.GetSection("FilesUrl").Value;

        xmlFilePath.Append(
            Path.Combine(pathFolder, 
                         model.Domain.ToLower().Trim() + "-" + model.LanguageCode.ToLower().Trim() + "-file.xml"));
        using (var w = File.CreateText(xmlFilePath.ToString()))
        {
            await w.WriteLineAsync(xmlString);
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** I found that when project is running under Docker, Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() will set as /app, but changing project running under Kestrel or IIS will make it as common windows directory path.

[image]

What is wrong in my code?
Why generated path contains "/app/"?

Comment: Each container has an isolated filesystem.  If the first service is saving files inside its own local `/app/wwwroot/...` tree, those files will not be accessible from the host or from other containers.

Answer (score 0):

The codes you showed seems have no relationship with  `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`,And For your requirement,you could try with `IWebHostEnviroment.WebRootPath`.

the WebrootPath of your webapi project could be setted as below in .net 6:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions{ ContentRootPath=@"......"   WebRootPath = "....");
```